# Get the number of the affected rows

Tags: java, jdbc

I am trying to get the number of the affected records of this query `SELECT mac, stop_name from behaviour where mac = ?` with the use of the `executeQuery`. How can I get the number of the affected rows?

**Code:**

```
if (behaviourExist.next()) {
    PreparedStatement prepared = con
            .prepareStatement("SELECT mac, stop_name from behaviour where mac = ?");
    prepared.setString(1, macD);
    ResultSet rsBehav = prepared.executeQuery();
    ArrayList<String> stopNameList = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (rsBehav.next()) {
        //int numberOfRows = rsBehav.getInt(1);
        String stNa = rsBehav.getString("stop_name");
        if (stNa.equals(nameShortestDistance)) {
            stopNameList.add(stNa);

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: http://www.coderanch.com/t/303346/JDBC/databases/find-number-rows-resultset

Comment: A select doesn't have a number of affected rows (== added, update or deleted).

Answer (score 1):

This is a read operation so it will not affect any row. If you want to get the number of row returned then you could do one of the below

1. Use a counter variable and increment it in the loop `while (rsBehav.next())`
2. Use a scrollable resultset

   ```
   PreparedStatement prepared = con.prepareStatement(
           "SELECT mac, stop_name from behaviour where mac = ?",
           ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
   ResultSet rsBehav = prepared.executeQuery();
   rsBehav.afterLast();
   int numRow = rsBehav.getRow();
   rsBehav.beforeFirst();
   ```

Here numRow will give you number or row returned,

Answer (score 0):

```
if (behaviourExist.next()) {
PreparedStatement prepared = con
        .prepareStatement("SELECT mac, stop_name from behaviour where mac = ?");
prepared.setString(1, macD);
ResultSet rsBehav = prepared.executeQuery();
ArrayList<String> stopNameList = new ArrayList<String>();
int numberOfRows = 0;
while (rsBehav.next()) {
    ++numberOfRows;
    String stNa = rsBehav.getString("stop_name");
    if (stNa.equals(nameShortestDistance)) {
        stopNameList.add(stNa);

    }
}
}
```

Here the variable numberOfRows will increment each time the loop runs which will give you the total number of rows in the resultSet.

Answer (score 0):

```
PreparedStatement prepared = con
        .prepareStatement(
         "SELECT (SELECT count(*) from where mac = ?),"
         " mac, stop_name from behaviour where mac = ?");
prepared.setString(1, macD);
prepared.setString(2, macD);
ResultSet rsBehav = prepared.executeQuery();
ArrayList<String> stopNameList = new ArrayList<String>();
while (rsBehav.next()) {
    int numberOfRows = rsBehav.getInt(1);
    String stNa = rsBehav.getString("stop_name");
    // ....
```